# Loop through a table list and get max values of each table in a different view/query

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a main_table which has a list of depts like.

**Depts**
HR
Sales
Engg
Admin
Accounts.

for each department there is a seperate table with the same name.
 And every table has fields-

emp_id
task
date_assigned
status.

I need to create a query which would pull out one record from each dept with the latest assigned date and fill it in a view. something like this

HR  910  16-01-14  Follow Up on Candidates

Answer (score 0):

for each table (tables)
{
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_assigned ASC LIMIT 1;
}

The SQL is the only really code the other is pseduo code.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use dynamic SQL for this

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(SELECT ''', depts, ''' dept, t.* FROM `', depts, 
                           '` t ORDER BY date_assigned DESC LIMIT 1)') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  INTO @sql
  FROM main_table;

SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' ORDER BY dept');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Sample output:

```
|  DEPT | EMP_ID |                    TASK |                  DATE_ASSIGNED |
|-------|--------|-------------------------|--------------------------------|
|    HR |    910 | Follow Up on Candidates | January, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
| Sales |    912 |      Follow up on leads | January, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/831b5d/1)** demo